# Donut Tutorial: My long sprinkles are looking thin and weird. How do I fix this issue?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I've been stuck on this issue for a long time and I've redone the tutorial twice and still get the same results. The long sprinkles are weirdly shaped and aren't sticking properly to the icing layer as shown below:
[image]

I have tried CTRL + A and applying scale, but this only gives weirder results as shown:
[image]

So I tried selecting the icing plus the cylinders (the long sprinkles), but this only made things worse:
[image]

For reference here is the node configuration:
[image]

Can someone please help me fix this issue once and for all?